# PyDev Eclipse jump to new line after new method

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When making a method in Eclipse using Python, is there a way to jump directly to next line, indented, after making input arguments? Instead of having to press end and enter, I keep missing that end key.

```
def _run_to_the_hills(self|):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Shift+Enter for that (which in Eclipse means: move cursor to end of line and do a new line there).

I also recommend you read: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/mastering-writing-code-on-pydev.html at least once -- this is the first tip there, but there are other nice things there that you should know about too ;)